Microsoft Orleans application docker issue
I have Microsoft Orleans application with .net8.0 framework
Project file myApp.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

also the docker file
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files and restore dependencies
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the remaining source files and build the application
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Stage 2: Build the runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the build output from the build stage
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

# Expose the gRPC port
EXPOSE 6565

# Define the entry point for the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]


I am building docker image with the following command
docker build -t myApp:latest .

then to run docker container using following command
docker run -d -p 6565:6565 --name myApp myApp:latest

it gives me an error
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /app/myApp.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.31 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64

As my app exposing grpc endpoint on 6565 I tried to change to http but it is giving me same error.
any help on above error would be appreciated and I have very basic knowledge of docker.

Error indicates Core 8.0 is not installed on machine.  Try downloading : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download.  Looks like Core 6.0.31 is installed on machine.

Thank you @jdweng for your comment
I have mentioned sdk while build application as
Stage 1: Build the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
Also specify runtime
Stage 2: Build the runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0
since I have all these it should run.
As per Microsoft troubleshooting steps
The error indicates the name, version, and architecture of the missing framework and the location at which it's expected to be installed.
I am try to decode and guess whats exact issue.

Latest core version is 8.0.6 not 8.0.0.  Do you have installed 8.0.0. or a different version?

yes @jdweng I tried with 8.0.6 but no luck.

thank @jdweng I resolved issue and posted the answer, it was miss from my end.

issue was I have given docker file name as DockerFile (F is capital letter). Hence our build process not picking up this file for building docker image.
it start building docker image with default build configuration which has .net6.0.31 version. as Microsoft troubleshooting steps "The error indicates the name, version, and architecture of the missing framework and the location at which it's expected to be installed." it is correct. Reference link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-discovery/troubleshoot-app-launch?pivots=os-linux
I just have to extra careful while giving name to docker file.

